# PHP Regular expression to extract data from a url source

Tags: php, regex

```
URL: somedoamin.com/r?ammem/hlaw:@field(DOCID+@lit(hj0011))
```

How can I extract the didit after hj, that is 001;

The format will always be `@lit(hj<integer>))`

Please help

I tried regular expression

```
\s+(lit)\d+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
@lit\(hj(\d+)\)\)
```

See the demo below.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS4kR9/3)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following :

```
(?<=@lit\(hj)\d*
```

It uses a positive look-behind to check for preceding `@lit(hj` and captures every digit up to the next closing parenthesis.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/iB2lY2/2)!

An alternative that captures anything up to the next parenthesis :

```
(?<=@lit\(hj)[^)]*
```

Comment: Watch out, this will match any characters, not just digits.

Comment: Indeed, added a digit-only alternative.

Comment: this one is uselessly too slow due to lookbehind. the one posted by ibarros is better imho

Comment: plus he said " integer" not "anything other than )" so again a useless [^)] that will check all characters not just the integers.

Comment: Ok I switched the main code and its alternative. You're right about the slowness, but some people will prefer having the whole logic implemented in the regex rather than having to select a specific group afterwards